# Export doesn't work when called from ssh session created through post-receive hook

Tags: bash, git, ssh, environment-variables, githooks

I have this Git post-receive hook in a remote repository that runs a bunch of commands in an SSH session:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -q admin@node-one << EOF
    export GOPATH=~/go
    export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
    echo $PATH
    echo $GOPATH
    cd ~/portfolio
    ./kill.sh
    git pull
    make build
    ./run.sh
EOF
```

And I am getting an error related to goimports not being found because `export` does not seem to work in this situation.

```
remote: /usr/lib/git-core:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
remote:
```

I can manually run the hook and it works just fine, but for some reason, it doesn't work when I run it through a `git push` from a remote repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inline content has shell expansions run by default, so your variables are being expanded in the text before the invoked shell ever sees them.  Quote anything in the delimiter to shut that off, or escape the bits you don't want expanded inline, e.g.

```
cat <<\EOD
    export GOPATH=~/go
    export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
EOD
```

or

```
cat <<EOD
    export GOPATH=~/go
    export PATH=\$GOPATH/bin:\$PATH
EOD
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! How about `source ~/.bashrc`, is there any way of invoking it in this situation? It doesn't seem to work even with your tweak.